# Spring data Jpa map multiples SQL views with some differente fields into a single entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have three views that that returns almost similar fields except one in each view, and I want to reuse the same entity for this views.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id") private String id;   
    @Column(name="fieldA") private String fieldA;   
    @Column(name="fieldB") private String fieldC;   
    @Column(name="fieldC") private String fieldC;   
}
```

The Views I am executing

First View:

```
select id, fieldA from myview;
```

Second view:

```
select id, fieldA, fieldB from myview2;
```

Thrid View:

```
select id, fieldA, fieldC from myview3;
```

First Repository

```
@Repository
public interface View1Repository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

@Query(nativeQuery=true)
MyEntity retrieveView1();
```

Second Repository

```
@Repository
public interface View2Repository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

@Query(nativeQuery=true)
MyEntity retrieveView2();
```

Third Repository

```
@Repository
public interface View3Repository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

@Query(nativeQuery=true)
MyEntity retrieveView3();
```

When I execute it it return Invalid Column Name, because it tries to map all the fields, including the ones that are not returning

Is there a way to reuse the same entity for this three querys..

PS. The examples are shorted the views and the Entity have way more fields

Answer (score 0):

Use [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

```
public interface EntityFieldA {
    String getFieldA();
}


public interface EntityFieldAB {
    String getFieldA();

    String getFieldB();
}

public interface EntityFieldAC {
    String getFieldA();

    String getFieldC();

}

@Repository
public interface View1Repository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Query("select new MyEntity (me.fieldA) from MyEntity ma")
    EntityFieldA retrieveView1();

    @Query("select new MyEntity (me.fieldA, me.fieldB) from MyEntity ma")   
    EntityFieldAB retrieveView2();

    @Query("select new MyEntity (me.fieldA, me.fieldC) from MyEntity ma")
    EntityFieldAC retrieveView3();
}
```